# Any 3 port NIC's made?

Tags: nic

basically want a 3 ethernet port NIC. is there really none of these available? cause i'm working on a project that only requires 3 ports,and the 4 port ones are ridiculously expensive. Yes,i know ebay is our friend,but they don't really ship to where i'm at. so just asking,has there been any 3 port NICs ever manufactured before?

Comment: You're not on planet earth?

Comment: What makes you think a potentially available 3port NIC would be considerable cheaper than a 4port variant? Most certainly it won't be 3/4th of the price ...

Comment: to answer first guy's question,i understand ebay to be majorically shipping in the US. I live at the other side f the world. just afraid of shipping costs         to the second guy,i didn't say considerably,i just meant that it would be slightly. although,i'd love to hear why you think it would not be worth it's price. Not as a challenge against you,merely as a curiosity.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a single port NIC and a dual-port NIC... or just use a 4-port card.

There's no real history of 3-port network add-in cards. I'm sure you can find something available in your price range. This is a commodity component.